# ccache - all files are "no input file"

Tags: ccache

I'm using ccache version 3.7.4 compiled by me like this:
*ccache compiler [compiler options]* but it doesn't seem to work

```
cache hit (direct)                     0
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                             0
cache hit rate                      0.00 %
no input file                         20
cleanups performed                     0
files in cache                         0
cache size                           0.0 kB
max cache size                       5.0 GB
```

The only field increases is the "no input file" per each compiled file, from ccache help pages it means *No input file was specified to the compiler* which isn't clear to me.

ccache.conf looks like this:

```
max_size = 5G
cache_dir = /local/ccache
temporary_dir = /tmp/ccache
umask = 002
direct_mode = true
```

What am I missing ?

EDIT:
found that I can see more debugs by setting CCACHE_LOGFILE.
Now I see this debug line for each file:

```
File.cpp is not a regular file, not considering as input file
No input file found
Failed; falling back to running the real compiler
```

running:
stat File.cpp
File: `File.cpp'
Size: 14924           Blocks: 32         IO Block: 1048576 **regular file**

Comment: Did you get this resolved? In what environment is this happening to you? Were you using Docker Desktop by any chance?